# Problems while following the tutorial: "Tutorial: Create a Custom Browser Guide" in Neo4j

Tags: html, database, browser, neo4j, asciidoc

I have some problems while following the tutorial: "Tutorial: Create a Custom Browser Guide" in Neo4j.
I get stuck at the point where I should pass the adoc file to HTML.

My prompt is giving me this feedback in Spanish

```
"/run.sh" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Translated into English:

```
"/run.sh" could no be recognized as an internal o external command, programm or executable file"
```

Here you can find the part of the tutorial, where I get stuck.

> Pass the test.adoc file to the run.sh script (as shown below) to
>   convert to the HTML slides.
>
> ```
> ./run.sh adoc/test.adoc html/test.html
>
>
> #optional arguments, leveloffset - to change the heading level up or down, base-url and additional attributes
>
> ./run.sh path/to/test.adoc path/to/test.html [+1] https://example.com/guides/test
>
>
> #run the local python server to serve on localhost:8001
> python http-server.py
> ```

Comment: Are you using Windows? Have you looked up the *general* error about scripts not being recognised?

Comment: Yes, I´m using windows, but I don´t know how to look up this type of general errors about scripts. Can you give me a hint? Thank you for editing my question.

Comment: Just put "could not be recognized as an internal or external command" into the search engine of your choice.